# Months with less than 31 days omitted from list

Tags: php, date

Consider the following code that was working perfectly yesterday, but now today (30th March), it has stopped working...

```
<form class="date">
<select name="date" onchange="this.form.submit()">

<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 60; ++$i) {
    $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
    $value = date('Y-m', $time);
    $label = date('F Y', $time);
    $nowvalue = date('Y-m');
    $nowlabel = date('F Y');
        if(isset($_GET['date'])) {
          if(strcmp($value,$_GET['date']) == 0) {
             //If 0, $value and $_GET['date'] are the same: The option is selected
             printf('<option value="%s" selected>%s</option>', $value, $label);
          } else {
             printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);
          }
        } else {
          if($value == $nowvalue) {
            printf('<option value="%s" selected>%s</option>', $value, $label);
          } else {
            printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);  
          }
    }
  }
  ?>
</select>
</form>
```

This outputs a select list of upcoming months, that onchange, reloads the page with a different query in the URL for the calendar on that page to react on.

If i manually update the query in the URL, it works fine, but this select list is repeating dates, have a look at the image below...

[image]

This cant be a coincidence that all of the months with the shortest days are missing, or in fact have been replaced with the same name as the month before?

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: These questions come up every 31st of the month...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Conde pointed out, this is because todays dates (the 31st) plus one month is actual May 1st, and April is skipped.

I did the following to set the date to the 1st of the month, then plus one month...

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 60; ++$i) {
    $firstofthismonth = '01-' . date('m-Y');
    $time = strtotime(sprintf($firstofthismonth . '+%d months', $i));
    $value = date('Y-m', $time);
    $label = date('F Y', $time);
    $nowvalue = date('Y-m');
    $nowlabel = date('F Y');
        if(isset($_GET['date'])) {
          if(strcmp($value,$_GET['date']) == 0) {
             //If 0, $value and $_GET['date'] are the same: The option is selected
             printf('<option value="%s" selected>%s</option>', $value, $label);
          } else {
             printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);
          }
        } else {
          if($value == $nowvalue) {
            printf('<option value="%s" selected>%s</option>', $value, $label);
          } else {
            printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);  
          }
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because when you loop through dates on a monthly basis on the 31st of the month you will come across months that have less than 30 days. PHP does automatically adjust the date to the last day of the month but instead goes to the end of the month and then adds the remaining days to it and gets the date that way which is the next month.

So if you get to February, which only has 28 days (most years) it will get to the 28th and add three days and give you March 3rd.

To solve this you need to set the date to the first day of the month and then iterate through the dates.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i understand whats happening now, changing that line didnt help though. I would have thought $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i)); would be the culprit because its +1 month from the 31st March, which comes out as May 1st if its 30 days right?

Comment: I was just looking at that. Unfortunately you removed the code that would have helped identify where to make the change but in a nutshell just take the date you are iterating through and change it to be the first of the month. That will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, i've figured it out now, will post a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an FYI as I realise that you've added your own answer.

You could instead use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to simplify your code (if you want).

So you could end up with something like:

```
<select name="date" onchange="this.form.submit()">

    <?php

    $selected = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', @$_GET['date'] . '-01') ?: new DateTime('first day of this month');

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++) {

        $date = (new DateTime('first day of this month'))->modify("+$i months");

        $select = $date == $selected ? 'selected' : '';

        printf('<option value="%s" %s>%s</option>', $date->format('Y-m'), $select, $date->format('F-Y'));

    }
    ?>

</select>
```

Hope this helps!